# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined in Opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I am working opencart. Here I am getting data from controller and need to display in frontend. So I am written the code as following:

This is the controller code:

```
public function filter($setting) {
    $this->load->language('module/color_filter');
    $json = array();

    if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($this->request->post['color'])) {

        $colors = explode(',',$this->request->post['color']);

        $products_arr = array();

        foreach ($setting['color'] as $setting_col) {
            foreach ($colors as $color) {
                if ($setting_col['color_name'] === $color) {
                    $products_arr = array_merge($products_arr,array_values($setting_col['products']));
                }
            }
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $products =array();

        foreach ($products_arr as $product) {
            if (!in_array($product,$products)) {
                $products[] = $product;
            }
        }

        $json['success'] = $products;

    } else {
        //$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_color');
    }
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

From the above code I am getting $json['success'] data through ajax as following:

Html code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
    <div class="list-group filter-group">
        <div class=" list-group-item color-swatches">
            <?php foreach ($colors as $color) { ?>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="color-filter[]" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php echo $color['color_name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $color['color_name']; ?>" style="background:<?php echo $color['color_code']; ?>; " />
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach ($setting as $set) { ?>
                <div><?php print_r($set); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.color-swatches input[type=\'checkbox\'').on('click',function() {
            var color = [];

            $('input[name^=\'color-filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
                color.push(this.value);
                alert("color names:"+color);
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=module/color_filter',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'color=' + color,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('.category-products+.clearfix').remove();
                },
                complete: function() {
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    $('.category-products').each(function() {
                        var el = $(this);
                        console.log("$this value:"+$(this));
                        var re = /\('(\d+)'/;
                        var sr = el.find('button').attr('onClick').match(re)[1];
                        alert("json:"+json['success']);
                        if (json['success'].indexOf(sr) !== -1) {
                            el.fadeIn('slow');
                        } else {
                            el.fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

I am getting the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Please can anyone help what is problem.

Comment: This will happen if `el.find('button')` doesn't find any buttons.

Comment: Okay Thanks @Barmar for reply, here I am using checkbox. when I clicked on that check box the related product to that need to get and display. So that I have changed it as "el.find('input[name^=\'color-filter\']').attr('onClick').match(re)[1];" still it occurs.

Comment: There's no `onclick` attribute in the `checkbox`.

Comment: Oh right I forget about that. Thanks @Barmar.